# CSS - what is the point of, when defining a rule, you to put the element and then the class, not just the class?

Tags: html, css, class, rule

So, I was looking at a tut on youtube the other day, and this guy kept defining css rules with classes really weirdly, and I wondered if one of u guys could explain the necessity of it: here is the code:

ul.class li{
  color:#fff
}

Why can't he just do:

.class{
  color:#fff
}

Thank you for reading my question, I hope you understand what I am asking for.

Video: https://youtu.be/2wCpkOk2uCg

P.S - Sorry for the giganticly large title

Answer (score 3):

When you put the element before the class, CSS only applies the styles to the members of that class that are of that specific element. 
For example, if you had .class applied to 3 headers and 3 paragraphs, writing p.class would only affect the paragraphs.

Comment: Oh I didn't see your comment, you made it much more clear for me, thanks 

Answer (score 1):

With `ul.class` you're saying "Apply this styles to all the `ul`'s with this class. If you only use `.class` you're saying "Apply this styles to ANYTHING that has this class". It's very different. :)

Comment: Omg, I did not know u would actually answer this quick lol, well that solves it, thx 

Answer (score 0):

I can think of at least two reasons to include the element name as well as the class:

1. **Specificity**, i.e., which CSS rule takes effect on a target element when multiple rules apply to to it. There is [a specificity algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) that determines which rule is applied when multiple rules are in competition.  This [awesome Specificity Calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/) is a great tool to help you understand the algorithm.  So, in short, including the element name *and* the class gives it additional weight.
2. **Documentation in your CSS**.  I tend to include the element as well as the class, e.g. `h1.customer-name`, to self-document what type of element the rule is being applied to.  When I see `.customer-name` without the element name, I am not totally confident in what type of HTML element it is.  Doing this means I don't have to keep the HTML structure in my head or consult the HTML repeatedly while I work on CSS.  But this is pretty dependent on one's approach to CSS as well as the tools used, so I'm not sure I would consider it a good idea across the board.

Answer (score 0):

And one more, but not least important thing. If you adding the tag name before the class name (such as span.class{}), so you got more specific rule and it's have bigger priority (no matter in which order that rules writter in css file). For example, if you write two rules:
.class { color: red }
and
span.class { color: blue }
you will get a blue text as a result.